# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/derby/derda/NetworkServerControl < Unsupported major.minor 49.0 >

Tags: java, derby

I set the Environment Variable both System Path to DERBY_HOME\bin and User variable name DERBY_HOME and value to where I kept the bin.Then using the cmd I enter the command startNetworkServer.bat but it is throwing the exception mentioned.

my derby version is 10.10.2.0
JDK version jdk1.7.0_07
JRE version jre7

I searched related exception but my JDK and JRE version are same.

How I can correct when my system path variable points to JDK and JRE version 7 or 1.7 and in the installation their is no jdk or jre version 1.5 or 5.Do I need to use lower version od derby 10.8.1.2?

Comment: I found the solution my environment CLASSPATH variable value was set to jre6 though I have installed jre7 after correcting jre7 my problem is solved.So if anyone facing this problem can also check whether the set the variables properly

Answer (score 3):

my jdk version is jdk1.7.0_79

and jre version jre7

and the derby version that I am using is 10.12.1.1 and it is working for me.

earlier when I was using the derby version  10.13.1.1 I was also getting the same type of error

then I found in the following link 
http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.13.1.1.cgi that  the derby version  10.13.1.1
supports Java SE 8 with JDBC 4.2 , and my jdk and jre version is jdk1.7.0_79 and jre7

So It seems due to version mismatch of jdk I was getting the error,So I downloaded the lower version of derby i.e 10.12.1.1
and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch of your java versions. Major Version 49 indicates that your class files are compiled with Java 1.5. It looks like you try to run your programm with an earlyer version of java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :  sudo update-alternatives --config java from the command line to change the java versions..